# C# System.InvalidCastException Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting an error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Decimal'

I could not solve it. I'm using Entity Framework to connect my own database. And the types are the same as the database columns.

I'm using Win11 and .NET 5 with Visual Studio 2019.

The compiler shows that error occurs at `EfCarDal` and in this line

```
return filter == null ? context.Set<Car>().ToList() : context.Set<Car>().Where(filter).ToList();
```

EfCarDal.cs

```
public class EfCarDal : ICarDal
{
    public void Add(Car car)
    {
        if (car.Description.Length>=2 && car.DailyPrice>0)
        {
            using (ReCapContext context = new ReCapContext())
            {
                var addedEntry = context.Entry(car);
                addedEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car name is too short or the price is not true.");
        }
    }

    public void Delete(Car car)
    {
        using (ReCapContext context=new ReCapContext())
        {
            var deletedEntry = context.Remove(car);
            deletedEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public Car Get(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> filter)
    {
        using (ReCapContext context = new ReCapContext())
        {
            return context.Set<Car>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
        }
    }

    public List<Car> GetAll(Expression<Func<Car,bool>> filter=null)
    {
        using (ReCapContext context = new ReCapContext())
        {
            return filter == null ? context.Set<Car>().ToList() : context.Set<Car>().Where(filter).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Update(Car car)
    {
        if (car.Description.Length > 2 && car.DailyPrice > 0)
        {
            using (ReCapContext context = new ReCapContext())
            {
                var updatedEntry = context.Update(car);
                updatedEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car name is too short or the price is not true.");
        }
    }
}
```

ICarDal.cs

```
public interface ICarDal : IEntityRepository<Car>
{
}
```

IEntityRepository.cs

```
public interface IEntityRepository<T> where T:class, IEntity ,new()
{
    List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

CarManager.cs

```
public class CarManager : ICarService
{
    ICarDal _carDal;

    public CarManager(ICarDal carDal)
    {
        _carDal = carDal;
    }

    public List<Car> GetAll()
    {
        return _carDal.GetAll();
    }

    public List<Car> GetCarsByBrandId(int id)
    {
        return _carDal.GetAll(c => c.BrandId == id);
    }

    public List<Car> GetCarsByColorId(int id)
    {
        return _carDal.GetAll(c => c.ColorId == id);
    }
}
```

ICarService.cs

```
public interface ICarService
{
    List<Car> GetAll();
    List<Car> GetCarsByBrandId(int id);
    List<Car> GetCarsByColorId(int id);
}
```

Car.cs

```
public class Car : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int ModelYear { get; set; }
    public decimal DailyPrice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Brand.cs

```
public class Brand : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Color.cs

```
public class Color : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

IEntity.cs

```
public interface IEntity
{
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CarManager carManager = new CarManager(new EfCarDal());

        foreach (var car in carManager.GetCarsByColorId(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) What line of your code does the stack trace point to?  b) You haven't shown any of your entities, nor any thing that has properties of either type `string` _or_ `decimal`, so I think you haven't shown us the pertinent code.

Comment: I edited the classes for your (b) section. but i did not understand what exactly mean with "stack trace point". The compiler says that there is an error in EfCarDal.cs class and GetAll function as i mention.

Comment: "And the types are the same with db columns" - are you reproducing the problem with this code?  I'm not seeing anything involving strings or decimals here, ...perhaps there's an error in the entity config mappings, or your connection string goes to another version of the db with different data types? Do you get the same error when the filter expression isn't specified (i.e. does the plain "get all" mapping work and it's the filter, or it still breaks without it and it's the mappings)?

Comment: DailyPrice mapping would be the prime suspect.

Comment: There was some incompatibility between the types in db (ModelYear and DailyPrice) I fix it and worked. thanks for helps